# Create an array with duplicated value from an array (PhP)

Tags: php, arrays, max

I want to create an new array with duplicated MAX value from an array
and put other duplicate value in an other array

```
      $etudiant = array ('a'=>'2','b'=>'5', 'c'=>'6', 'd'=>'6', 'e'=>'2');
```

and i want this result

```
     $MaxArray =  array ('c'=>'6', 'd'=>'6');
     $otherarray1 =  array ('a'=>'2', 'e'=>'2');
```

Thank you !

Comment: Would `$otherArray` be better named `MinArray`? Or should it in fact contain `'b'=>5`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, find the maximum value:

```
$etudiant = array ('a'=>'2','b'=>'5', 'c'=>'6', 'd'=>'6', 'e'=>'2');
$maxValue = max($etudiant);
```

Second, find values that appear more than once:

```
$dups = array_diff_assoc($etudiant, array_unique($etudiant));
```

Lastly, check the original arrays for values matching either `$maxValue` or values that are listed in `$dups`:

```
$MaxArray = $OtherArray = $ElseArray = array();
foreach ($etudiant as $key => $value) {
    if ($value == $maxValue) {
        $MaxArray[$key] = $value;
    } else if (in_array($value, $dups)) {
        $OtherArray[$key] = $value;
    } else {
        $ElseArray[$key] = $value;
    }
}
```

You'll get:

```
$MaxArray: Array
(
    [c] => 6
    [d] => 6
)
$OtherArray: Array
(
    [a] => 2
    [e] => 2
)
```

Note: I wasn't sure if you wanted the `$MaxArray` to contain the maximum value elements only if it appears more than once in the source array. If so, just change the `max` call to:

```
$maxValue = max($dups);
```

Comment: last question  ,  can I put  my  [code]<'b'=>'5[/code}    in an other array  like
$rest=  array ('c'=>'5');

Comment: @user763045: Yes, just add an extra `else` clause. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `array_values(array_intersect($array1, $array2))` to get duplicated values, and then make a loop to capture the keys which have those values and store them into another array.

```
$dups = array_values(array_intersect($array1, $array2))
$max = max($dups);
$result = array();

foreach ($array1 as $key => $value){
  if (in_array($value, $dups)) {
    $result[$key] = $value;
  }
}

foreach ($array2 as $key => $value){
  if (in_array($value, $dups)) {
    $result[$key] = $value;
  }
}

$maxArray = array();
foreach ($dups as $key => $value) {
  if ($value == $max){
    $maxArray[$key] = $value;
  }
}

// results are in $dups and $maxArray
```

Comment: If you look at the question, I don't think the OP is concerned about duplicates as much as finding the elements for max and min values.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to find elements with the min and max values from an array, the following will work.

```
// get min keys
$min_value = min($etudiant);
$min_keys = array_keys($etudiant, $min_value);

// get max keys
$max_value = max($etudiant);
$max_keys = array_keys($etudiant, $max_value);
```

You could then either rebuild your example arrays with these keys in a loop. Or access them directly, i.e. `$etudiant[$min_keys]`.

Check out the documentation for [array_keys](http://php.net/array_keys), [min](http://php.net/min), [max](http://php.net/max)